# Rails 5 - Export to XL/CSV but through Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, csv

I've been following this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast) on CSV/Excel Export but I'm having a bit of an issue with the association logic.

**CSV Confusion/Issue**

In my `Collection Model` I have

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :card_collections
  has_many :cards, through: :card_collections

  def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{name}

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      all.each do |collection|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| collection.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end

  # validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**CSV Export**

```
name
Demo 2
HEHHEHEEHHE
```

name is the column name
Demo 2 is the first Collection
HEHHEHEEHHE is the second Collection

I need far more information, but once I get 'one' parameter I can go from there. But this isn't working.'name' will return the name of ALL collections, which isn't quite what I want at all, but I'm also trying to get information about the 'cards' in the collection (Referenced by cards_collection)
To give you an example - In console I would type:
`c = Collection.last`
`c.cards.first.name` and I would get the first cards name.
I'm unsure if I should be making this self.to_csv function in the `Card_collections` controller, the `Cards` controller or what. I'm found a lot of similar questions regarding CSV through associations but nothing that has led me to a solution

**Excel Confusion**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Card Collection">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Text</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Set</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% @collection.card_collections.each do |collection| %>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= collection.card.name %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= collection.card.text %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= collection.card.set %></Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Is a sample script - I actually have this wrapped in an 'each' because if they choose Excel I'll allow them to get one sheet per 'collection'.

To give you an idea of the relation, my **`Collection View`** looks like -

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div class="center"><%= @collection.name %></div><br />
<div class="center">Made By: 
<strong>
  <% if @collection.public %>
    <%= link_to @collection.user.name, {:controller => "users", :action => "show", :id => @collection.user.id} %><br />
  <% else %>
    Anonymous<br />
  <% end %>
</strong>
Total Cards: <%= @collection.card_collections.sum(:card_counts) %>
Distinct Cards: <%= @collection.card_collections.count %> <br />
</div>
  <% @collection.card_collections.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
  <div class='row'>
    <% group.each do |card| %>
      <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4'>
        <%= image_tag(card.card.image_url, class: "img-responsive") %>
        <h3>
          <%= link_to card.card.name, {:controller => "cards", :action => "show", :id => card.card.id }%>
        </h3>
        <div><%= card_text_swap(card.card.text) %></div>
        <div><span class='cardLabel'>Set</span>: <i class="ss ss-<%= card.card.set.downcase %> ss-3x ss-<%= card.card.rarity.downcase %>"></i>  
               <span class="setName"><%= card.card.setName %></span>
        </div>
        <div>Total in Collection: <%= card.card_counts %></div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_collection_path(@collection) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', collections_path %>
```

I struggled in making the view originally but finally got it working, and I'm trying to use the same logic in the Excel export, but it's not rendering properly. (Immediate nil errors, so I think this might be a failure on my part.)

**Additional Info** All of this is stored within ActiveDirectory, and being rendered to a view currently. Unsure what other information I should offer.

**New Excel Issue**

**Collections_Controller**

```
  def show
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { render text: @collection.to_csv }
      format.xls { send_data @collection.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
  <%= link_to "CSV", collection_path(format: "csv") %> |
  <%= link_to "Excel", collection_path(format: "xls") %>
```

CSV is now working - Excel is not.

Error Provided:

```
ArgumentError in CollectionsController#show
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Comment: What you want to get in CSV file?

Comment: @ZaurAmikishiyev A basic amount of informaiton would be
CardName, and CardSet
`c.card_collections.first.card.name` and `c.card_collections.first.card.set` is how I would get those in Rails Console respectively. The `Collection View` shows how I call it to the view

Comment: you need to pass a collection_id to collection_path and you only pass format

Comment: send_data @collection.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") will not generate data in XLS format.

So for xls just have format.xls on its line. This will make rails search for show.xls.erb files in app/views/collections/ and there you need to have that xml file with inline ruby code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"def self.to_csv" defines a class method. If you want to list cards for given Collection you need to define and call (in show method of your collections controller) an instance method.

So I changed your to_csv in the following way:

```
def to_csv
  attributes = %w{name}

  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes
    cards.each do |card|
      csv << attributes.map{ |attr| card.send(attr) }
    end
  end
end
```

This is how to call to_csv in your controller:

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { render text: @collection.to_csv }
    end
  end
end
```

for Excel:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Card Collection">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Text</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Set</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% @collection.cards.each do |card| %>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= card.name %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= card.text %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= card.set %></Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

And generally when you want to access cards for given @collection just use `cards` relation and you will not need extra `.card` when you access attributes of given card.

Comment: Disregard - I guess it was just cache. It's working perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your help!